# Encryption Comparing Hashed&Salted Password upon Login

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, salt

I have a simple password encrypter that gives me a hashed/salted password to store in my database when a user registers. Code:

```
public static string GenerateHashWithSalt(string enteredPassword, string enteredSalt)
    {
        string sHashWithSalt = enteredPassword + enteredSalt;
        byte[] saltedHashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sHashWithSalt);
        System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm algorithm = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(saltedHashBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
```

When a user logs in, I presume I can't simply put the entered password back through this code and compare as it would give me a different result. How can I *simply* compare the stored password against the entered log in password?

Comment: Maybe i don't remember correctly my cryptography lessons, but it's exactly what you should do, when you get the password from the user you salt and has it, and then compare to the salted+hashed password in the DB. it's should be the same string. there is no randomness it's a completely deterministic function.

Comment: Hash algorithms are idempotent: same input in = same output out.

Comment: Note that single iteration SHA-256 is not appropriate password hash. I'd use PBKDF2 with at least 10000 iterations using the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the account is created, you would have a `password hash` column, which would be populated by `GenerateHashWithSalt(password, salt);` where the password is provided by them and then the salt is randomly generated. The salt would then be stored alongside the password hash.

Then, when you need to see if a username/password is valid, you'd use `storedpassword == GenerateHashWithSalt(providedPassword, saltFromDb)` or some such. If they come out the same, then you know they entered the correct password

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks. I was also having a bit of trouble with the hash length, the database was only taking 25 characters and the hash was well over that so they did not match. However, i have solved this issue too. Thanks again

Comment: @ZeeeeeV I'll go on to say be VERY careful writing your own authentication. It's very tricky and there are very subtle things that can appear to work, but later end up leaking your user account info. Also, if you worked around that issue by only trimming the hashes to 25 characters, you're basically making your hash weaker. Expand the database column or make a new one

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up a quick tutorial on how salted-hashed-password-equivalent schemes work. However, based on the fact that you are asking the question I should caution you that *this is only the first step in ensuring a secure logon process*.  You should hire a security expert or purchase an off-the-shelf solution rather than attempting to roll your own if you are a beginner at this. The number of ways to make an inobvious mistake that makes the system insecure is *enormous*.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/salt/

Comment: Thanks for the article, surely it helps to spread the knowledge of hashing passwords. Maybe you could exchange the "modern" MD5 with a key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2, that would make the hashes a lot safer.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a way to compare passwords, maybe this will help: [encryption/decryption](http://blog.xoftc.com/?p=42)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of steps to do this correctly.

First you need 3 things:

1. A password provided by the user. (let's call it *p*)
2. A random string of characters that you create. This is known as the salt (we'll call it *s*)
3. A cryptographic hash function (well call it *h*(x))

With the above three things we can calculate *h*' which is what we want to store: *h*' = *h*( *s* + *p* )

The user's password is never stored. We only store *s* and *h*' in our database.

The salt doesn't need to be encrypted. It just needs to be be unique for every password in the database.

When the user tries to log in again in the future you will recalculate *h*' using the original salt that is stored in the database. If the new *h*' is equal to what is in the database then the user's password is the same.